# What is the right way to setup navigation drawer in react native

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Hello guys im a react native beginner and i created some small projects but in everyone of them my navigation is wrong ( works but not as i wanted ) exactly on the drawer look at my code and as you can see  the MainStack , Login and StartUpScreen are showing on the drawer when open it in the app and i don't want that ! i just put them there so i can navigate between them ! is there any better way or someone who can show me how to do it right ?

```
const RootNavigation = (props) => {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const screenOptions = {
    headerShown: true,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    headerTintColor: "aqua",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  };

  const drawerOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
  };

  const AppStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="ProductsOverview"
      screenOptions={screenOptions}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProductsOverview"
        component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          title: "All Products",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
              <Item
                title="Cart"
                iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-cart" : "ios-cart"}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("CartScreen");
                }}
              />
            </HeaderButtons>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProductsDetail"
        component={ProductDetails}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          title: route.params.productTitle,
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="CartScreen"
        component={CartScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Cart Items",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OrdersScreen"
        component={OrdersScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Orders ",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EditingProductScreen"
        component={EditingProductScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          title: "Editing",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
              <Item
                title="Cart"
                iconName={
                  Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-arrow-back" : "ios-arrow-back"
                }
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("User Products");
                }}
              />
            </HeaderButtons>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddingProductScreen"
        component={AddingProductScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          title: "Adding",
          headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
              <Item
                title="Cart"
                iconName={
                  Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-arrow-back" : "ios-arrow-back"
                }
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("User Products");
                }}
              />
            </HeaderButtons>
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
  function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <Button
          title="LOGOUT"
          onPress={() => {
            dispatch(authActions.logout());
          }}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={drawerOptions}
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="StartUpScreen" component={StartUpScreen} />

        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="MainStack" component={AppStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Products Overview"
          component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerShown: true,
            title: "All Products",
            headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "white",
            },
            headerTintColor: "aqua",
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
            headerRight: () => (
              <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item
                  title="Cart"
                  iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-cart" : "ios-cart"}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("CartScreen");
                  }}
                />
              </HeaderButtons>
            ),
          })}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Orders"
          component={OrdersScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            title: "Orders ",
            headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "white",
            },
            headerTintColor: "aqua",
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="User Products"
          component={userProducts}
          options={({ navigation }) => ({
            headerShown: true,
            title: "User Products",
            headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: "open-sans-bold" },
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "white",
            },
            headerTintColor: "aqua",
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
            headerRight: () => (
              <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item
                  title="Cart"
                  iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-add" : "ios-add"}
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("AddingProductScreen");
                  }}
                />
              </HeaderButtons>
            ),
          })}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default RootNavigation;
```